# Spring MVC form validation: how to make field optional?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, validation

I have a form (Spring 3 MVC project) and I'm using DTO (data transfer object) for data validation. Data is sent to a controller and I'm checking for it's validity with `BindingResult.hasErrors()` method and appropriate annotations. I'm going to simplify here since I'm having a problem with numeric fields.

**DTO:**

```
public class Item {

    private String discount;

    @Digits(integer = 15, fraction = 2)
    public String getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

}
```

If I submit form with nothing written in `discount` field, `BindingResult.hasErrors()` will return true with message

`numeric value out of bounds (<15 digits>.<2 digits> expected)`.

What I want to accomplish is that `discount` field can be empty but if something is written in it it should be in numerical format provided by `@Digits` annotation. How can I do that?

Comment: According to the JavaDoc, `@Digits` should accept null values, and empty form fields are normally translated to null. I haven't verified this, but would expect that they've tested this case. I would run a test without the constraint, to verify that I'm not getting something unexpected in the field (perhaps due to some converter running as part of the request stack).

Comment: With or without constraint I'm getting same result. If field is empty I'm getting empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is configuring Spring to convert **empty String** to **null**. You can achieve this by registering a `StringTrimmerEditor` in your FormController `initBinder` method :

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}
```

[StringTrimmerEditor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/StringTrimmerEditor.html)

Then as specified by parsifal, `@Digits` consider `null` value as valide.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your custom validation annotation. An explanation can be found on the spring documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html , par 5.7.2.2